# Does the page down key work in Android apps running on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os

So I'm looking to buy a Chromebook that supports Android apps but I use <kbd>PageDown</kbd>  a lot.  On Chromebook in browser it is activated by the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>.  Can anyone comment if it works on Android apps on a supported Chromebook?  This a yes or no question. I understand it works in Chrome but that isn't new and I already own one.  I only have access to Android devices not chrome OS(with Android Apps installed) so I would like to simply state that the <kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowDown</kbd> do not work in Android which is not really on topic for this site.  Hacks are acceptable.

Comment: @ErezZrihen There isn't anything inherently wrong with a question that can be answered with just a "yes" or "no". Though it would be good *on the answerer's part* if they could include more details.

Comment: For those voting to close, **this question is not about the Android operating system, nor an Android device, and is NOT off-topic on Super User**. It is a question [about Chrome OS](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9510/are-questions-about-chrome-os-on-topic).

Comment: Edited to make clear that it refers to pgdn key, see chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39740878#39740878

Comment: I think you can improve this question by adding a related question: "If it doesn't work, is there a way/hack to make it work?". I'd add it, but since I don't have full editing privilege here, my edit suggestion could be seen as changing author's intent.

Comment: @AndrewT I have added hacks are acceptable but having messed with rooted Android this isn't an a carried over feature I would think even with hacks.

Comment: Last but not least, could you describe the function of PageDown here? Do you mean to scroll down the screen by a large amount, or literally simulating pressing the PageDown button (because... an app may probably customize key binding)? This might solve [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that I've been feeling while reading this question.

Comment: @AndrewT. So I want the PageDown Key to work just like it works in macOS and in Windows(and Ubuntu & old Chromebooks.  This is the most used key on my keyboard behind probably space.  I do a bunch of reading.  I have gotten access to a Chromebook with Android app support and answered this question.  No I don't want a partial scroll down I want it to move the size of the window regardless of the size of the window(this is how it works everywhere IME).  This could be a setting(in regards to should this work by default in applications or should applications implement there own behavior).

Comment: It appears none of the Applications I tried besides obviously Chrome support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  So I have access to a Chromebook with Android app support for a couple days if anyone has any questions I am happy to answer them.  Basically this isn't supported in Android apps on Chromebooks.  I tried both Alt+ArrowDown and a PageDown key on an external keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

As per googles support pages, you can install android applications directly onto a chromebook - [Google support page for android applications on chromebooks](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7021273?hl=en-GB). Please note, it doesn't specifically say you need to be running Chrome OS but this is presumed.

You also need to check that the chromebook you're planning to get, is listed as one of the devices that supports the play store (which is how you install android applications). You can see a list [on the Chromium-os site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps)

Comment: Note. I don't know if you can 'side load' applications onto a chromebook that doesn't already have the play store.

Comment: Forgive me but this doesn't appear to answer the question . The Page down key doesn't work in Android for phones or tablets I have tested it.

Comment: @William So submit that as an answer be prepared to backup that statement

Comment: @Ramhound The point William is making here is that this answer entirely misses the point of the question.